# remote server returned an error 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest

I have to call a method of web service which contains array as part of parameters.
I dont want to pass any value for the parameter of type Array.
                I tried passing null,""(empty)but the web Method call returns 'remote server returned an error 500 internal server error 'as error.I am unable to figure out the cause?Need some help.
Here is my code

```
string post_data = "SessionID=" + sessionID + "&From=" + "" + "&To=" + "" + "&Changed=" + "" ;

// this is where we will send it
string uri = "test.asmx";

// create a request
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
request.Method = "POST";

// turn our request string into a byte stream
byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(post_data);

// this is important - make sure you specify type this way
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();

// now send it
requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
requestStream.Close();

// grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status code
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
```

Comment: For array parameter instead of sending empty string ("") send its value as `null` and request.ContentType should be "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" instead of "application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8"

Comment: enable remote debugging and add server error here

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply this suggestion dosent seem to work! Any other thing you would like to pointout

Comment: Are you sure the service can deal with null parameter?

Comment: If I add service reference and call the methods by passing null parameters then service returns response but when I try with SOAP or simple httpwebrequest it returns 'remote server returned an error 500 internal server error'.

Comment: Initially I thought null parameter is the problem but the exact problem is 'request.GetRequestStream().Length' exception'.

Comment: Please any help on how to resolve 'request.GetRequestStream().Length' exception'.